# Appcelerator titanium with atom ide

Tags: titanium-mobile, atom-editor, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-titanium, tishadow

I use atom to build titanium app, the titanium studio is very very slow while
Atom is a lightweight IDE, i followed this [crate titanium app with atom ide](https://github.com/m1ga/titanium_with_atom)

the only thing i want to know if is how to install modules or widget from atom ? and using tishadow too with atom?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The command is:

```
titanium build -p android -T device --shadow
```

According to http://tishadow.yydigital.com/getting%20started/

Install from atom using the package installer on the settings page.